# Custom for a mourner to be chosen to read the haftora every week

Tags: minhag, torah-service, mourning-aveilus

The Chabad rabbi near me has the custom of taking (for himself) both the kaddish recitation after the Torah reading (when applicable) and the reading of the haftorah on Shabbat — specifically when he is in a mourning period (thirty days for a close relative or twelve months for a parent).

Is there a source for this minhag?

Sources/rationales for this custom would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Kitzur Shulchan Aruch ([204:4](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0203_L2)) mentions (almost by the way) that a mourner gets to say the Haftara.

> יִשְׁתַּדְּלוּ **לַעֲשוֹת נַחַת רוּחַ לַנְּשְׁמָה** לְהִתְפַּלֵּל לִפְרָקִים לִפְנֵי הַתֵּבָה, **וְלִקְרוֹת הַהַפְטָרָה**, וּלְבָרֵךְ בְּזִמּוּן, וְלִתֵּן צְדָקָה, וְלִלְמוֹד אוֹ לִשְׂכּוֹר מִי שֶׁיִלְמַד עֲבוּרוֹ
>
> [Mourners] should try **to bring joy to the deceased** by leading the prayers **and reading the *Haftara***, and to say *zimun* [lead *bentsching*], to give charity, and to learn or hire someone to learn in the deceased's merit.
> ( *free translation* )

So it's not even Chabad-specific, by was known widely by the mid-1800's. (I cannot find the Kitzur's source.)

Comment: just to add to specifically answer the question (according to chabad custom) in sefer haminhogim (chabad) page 15 that the minhag is to try to say the kaddish after krias hatorah. there is a letter from the rebbe regarding diffrent minhagim about an ovel (iggros kodesh cheilek gimmul page 7) one of the things mentioned there is that an ovel should get maftir for the entire 11 months

Comment: It only says he does that stuff לִפְרָקִים not assumed that he would or has the right to do it every time

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure regarding the specifics you have mentioned. in sefer haminhagim it says, "A mourner endeavors to undertake the public reading of the Torah in shul on Monday and Thursday mornings and at Minchah on Shabbos" (page 178) in the footnotes the source was this was a directive of the Frierdiker Rebbe. I think the best and most obvious solution to finding an answer to your question is to simply ask the man. after all you have stated he is close by to your location

Comment: He is doing none of those things (Laining). The reason I do not wish tho ask personally is for personal reasons

Comment: try chabad.org ask the rabbi

Comment: A good point. Will do

Comment: @soandos If you do, please consider posting that answer here!

Comment: Of course, will do