# When is a Person Obligated to Lead the Davening?

Tags: halacha, minhag, tefilla

On various occasions I have heard somebody in shul declare that they have a *chiyyuv* to daven - an obligation, that is, to serve as *sheliach hatzibbur*: to represent the congregation in their leading of *tefillah*. To be honest, I've never actually understood what constitutes this *chiyyuv*, and have guessed (though am probably wrong) that it relates to an obligation to say the *amidah* twice.

Is there really such a thing as a "*chiyyuv* to daven"? When does a person possess this obligation, and how much of the davening does it require them to lead? I have only ever heard people say this during *shacharit*, but does it apply to *mincha* (and to *maariv*) as well? Can it be limited to *mussaf*, on a day when *mussaf* is read?

Secondly, what happens if there is more than one person in shul with this *chiyyuv*? Is there a scale of obligations, with some *chiyyuvim* trumping others, or are all obligations equal?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18243/759

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kitzur Shulchan Aruch [204:4](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/45538/440) records a custom to lead the prayers during the time when a mourner is saying Kaddish. This is the "obligation" you are hearing about.

In terms of which ones trump others, the rules in practice are to follow the same rules as with Kaddish itself ([see here](http://www.theyeshivaworld.com/coffeeroom/topic/chiyuv-for-shliach-tzibbur-order-of-precedence) and [here](http://www.jewish-funeral-guide.com/tradition/precedence-rules.htm)). In larger communities you will see people try to make a second Minyian when they lose out on the preferences.

It applies to Mincha and Maariv as well, but it doesn't apply to Shabbos and Yom Tov and (I don't think this is universal) days when Musaf is said (my observation) - except for a Yartzeit, where it applies in all those cases (see [here](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/371317/jewish/The-Yartzeit-Anniversary.htm) #5), even Rosh Hashana and Yom Kippur (although the standard Gabbi response seems to be "G-d made you an orphan, not a Chazzan, so no.").

Comment: Yishai, in response to your last point, I've davened in schuls where a jahrzeit had caused a great tircha with his attempts to properly follow the nusach (if you've davened in my town's Chabad on a weekday, there's a good chance that this will happen)

Comment: Although a person is paying membership this only allows him to say kaddish. To daven before the amud (lead the davvening) he also has to be 'mruzeh l'kahal'. Just because he is a chiyuv others dont have to suffer.